# Расчет стоимости на jquery

Tags: jquery

Данный калькулятор рассчитывает цену проката авто в зависимости от сезона, на каждый из 3 сезонов задано 5 разных цен. Мне нужно усложнить его, добавив еще и 3 разных авто, чтоб на каждый автомобиль на каждый сезон была своя цена. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это сделать? Все, где есть id="type-auto", уже добавлено к исходному коду мной, а вот заставить работать и добавить еще один уровень вложенности никак не получается. Опыта не хватает. Большое спасибо за помощь!

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="type-auto">Auto</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="type-auto">
      <option value="0">Выберите сезон</option>
      <option value="1">KIA</option>
      <option value="2">Ford</option>
      <option value="3">Opel</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="type-direction">Сезон</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="type-direction">
      <option value="0">Выберите сезон
      </option>
      <option value="1">03/01 - 09/04; 16/10-20-12
      </option>
      <option value="2">10/04 - 09/06; 15/09 – 15/10
      </option>
      <option value="3">10/06 -14/09; 21/12 – 03/01
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="number-sessions">Количество дней</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="number-sessions">
      <option value="0">Выберите кол-во дней</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="total-price">Итоговая цена</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total-price">
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
  var $auto = $('#type-auto')
       ,$dir = $('#type-direction')
       ,$num = $('#number-sessions')
       ,$tot = $('#total-price')
       ,prices = {
       // номер_сезона: { номер_кол-ва дней: цена, }
        1: { 1: 30, 2: 45, 3: 60, 4: 75, 5: 90 },
         2: { 1: 35, 2: 50, 3: 65, 4: 80, 5: 95 },
         3: { 1: 40, 2: 55, 3: 70, 4: 85, 5: 100 }
       };
    
    function update() {
      var auto = $auto.val(); // значение авто
      var dir = $dir.val(); // значение сезона
      var num = $num.val(); // значение кол-ва дней
      $tot.val( prices[dir]  &&  prices[dir][num]);
     
    }
    
    // слушать события обновления значений
    $auto.on('change', update);
    $dir.on('change', update);
    $num.on('change', update);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле все просто. Объект `prices` надо расширить для значений машин, и в выводе цены добавить наши авто. Для наглядности, к ценам вперед я добавил номер авто.

```js
var $auto = $('#type-auto'),
    $dir = $('#type-direction'),
    $num = $('#number-sessions'),
    $tot = $('#total-price'),
    prices = {
        1: { // kia
            // номер_сезона: { номер_кол-ва дней: цена, }
            1: {1: 130, 2: 145, 3: 160, 4: 175, 5: 190},
            2: {1: 135, 2: 150, 3: 165, 4: 180, 5: 195},
            3: {1: 140, 2: 155, 3: 170, 4: 185, 5: 1100}
        },
        2: {//ford
            // номер_сезона: { номер_кол-ва дней: цена, }
            1: {1: 230, 2: 245, 3: 260, 4: 275, 5: 290},
            2: {1: 235, 2: 250, 3: 265, 4: 280, 5: 295},
            3: {1: 240, 2: 255, 3: 270, 4: 285, 5: 2100}
        },
        3: {//opel
            // номер_сезона: { номер_кол-ва дней: цена, }
            1: {1: 330, 2: 345, 3: 360, 4: 375, 5: 390},
            2: {1: 335, 2: 350, 3: 365, 4: 380, 5: 395},
            3: {1: 340, 2: 355, 3: 370, 4: 385, 5: 3100}
        },
    };


function update() {
    var auto = $auto.val(); // значение авто
    var dir = $dir.val(); // значение сезона
    var num = $num.val(); // значение кол-ва дней
    $tot.val(prices[auto] && prices[auto][dir] && prices[auto][dir][num]);

}

// слушать события обновления значений
$auto.on('change', update);
$dir.on('change', update);
$num.on('change', update);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="type-auto">Auto</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="type-auto">
      <option value="0">Выберите сезон</option>
      <option value="1">KIA</option>
      <option value="2">Ford</option>
      <option value="3">Opel</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">

    <label for="type-direction">Сезон</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="type-direction">
      <option value="0">Выберите сезон
      </option>
      <option value="1">03/01 - 09/04; 16/10-20-12
      </option>
      <option value="2">10/04 - 09/06; 15/09 – 15/10
      </option>
      <option value="3">10/06 -14/09; 21/12 – 03/01
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="number-sessions">Количество дней</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="number-sessions">
      <option value="0">Выберите кол-во дней</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="total-price">Итоговая цена</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total-price">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО! 3 дня бился, пробовал разные варианты, очень похожие на этот, но знаний не хватило, и в нете не смог найти. Еще раз большое спасибо!